# Understanding Lambda for calling API's

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am totally new to Lambda (or AWS) and am still to build knowledge and experience around it.

Now, I was building an app where in it requires to fetch data from twitter Hashtag.

If I got it correctly, Twitter restricts number of API calls we make every minute(?) hence we need to have a backend and needs to have oAuth2 authentication.

In a simple express app, I would have done an API call in the global scope to get the data and use setInterval to hit that API after every x minute so as to not exceed number of limits.

Now based on the very vague understanding, I guess Lambda runs function when we need it, Hence is it right to assume that we can't use lambda for such use cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old-school way of doing this is to run a cron job that fires a particular script every so often.  The AWS way of running code periodically is using CloudWatch scheduled events.  You can configure how often you want to run a given target, and set the target as a lambda function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

[image]